# No Swift settings in Xcode 5 project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8

I am trying to add some Swift code to an existing project created in Xcode 5 and I get a crash whenever I try to automatically generate a bridging header. Looking in my project settings, I think it is because there are no Swift Compiler settings. Anyone know of a way to migrate a project to Xcode 6 settings or do I need to re-create the project?

Comment: Swift support requires Xcode6

Comment: @PaulDardeau I think you misunderstood my question. I have an Objective C project created with Xcode 5 that I open in Xcode 6. However, I can't add a Swift file because when I try to create the bridging header, Xcode crashes. I think it has something to do with the missing Swift Compiler build settings.

Comment: For me the swift compiler settings wouldn't show up until I'd generated a bridging header so I suspect your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @OllieEdwards The problem is the first beta of XCode would crash when trying to generate a bridging header. The issue was fixed in beta 2 I believe.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only solution I've found for this is to create a new target. Make sure to select "Swift" as the language choice for the new target. Something in the creation of a target with this selection enables the Swift build settings.

**Update:** Creating a new target containing Swift worked because of what it contained. When I removed the template Swift files from the new target the Swift-specific build settings disappeared from the project again.

The real indicator to Xcode on whether to show those build settings is whether the target contains at least one `.swift` file. So, the easiest solution is to simply add a new Swift file. This also triggers Xcode to prompt you about automatically creating an Objective-C bridging header - which you'll need in any project that has some Objective-C in it.

Comment: Yah, I think that's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around this by manually adding some Swift settings to the `project.pbxproj` file.

In the attributes block of the PBXProject section, add:

```
LastSwiftUpdateCheck = 0720;
```

In the XCBuildConfiguration section, add this to the Debug build settings for the project (the first and larger block of settings):

```
SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = "-Onone";
```

And add this to the Debug build settings for the target:

```
OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS = "-DDEBUG";
```

And this to the Release build settings for the target:

```
OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS = "";
```

When you reopen the project, the Swift settings will be available.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the swift settings were missing for me.

Adding a new Swift file to my target, also added the build settings.

Removing the only swift file, seemed to have also removed all the build settings. So make sure you have a swift file in your list of compiled sources.