# Xcode Swift Build Settings Missing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, settings

I have a project that contains an App, a custom keyboard and an embedded framework. A bit of context...
The app was created as an ObjC project a while ago, the keyboard was also started as ObjC. The embedded framework was added later as ObjC as well.

The project is being converted to Swift. I can see the Swift compiler options in the project but setting a value at the project level trickles down into User-Defined settings at the target level.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm trying to explain.
On the left is the project-level settings, on the right are the target-level settings.

[image]

Please note that creating a new project with the same setup does show the Swift compiler settings.

How can I make these settings show up? What are the impacts of having these settings in User-Defined? Are they going to act the same way?

Comment: have you solved this? I met the same with an old target

Comment: This is [answered over on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24169377). Mentioning here as this is now the top hit on Google for "Xcode build settings missing swift".

Comment: @starkos if you answer the question with the link, I can accept it and give you internet points.